# Merge multiple minified javascript files in recursive folders into one file

Tags: javascript, windows, concatenation, bundling-and-minification

I have multiple minified files in multiple folder in a single folder for minified js.

I wish to create single js file from all of minified js. 
Now I am using type command to concatenate all files like

```
type .\\v2\\dist\\js\\*.js >> .\\build\\a.min.js   &&   type .\\v2\\dist\\js\\config\\*.js >> .\\build\\a.min.js && ...
```

Like wise I need to append all recursive folders.
Is there any clean way to do it.

Please don't suggest using Gulp or Grunt as we are already in process of removing them & using Webpack. Any code using webpack or using npm or simple command line is welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069173/recursive-cat-all-the-files-into-single-file

Comment: I'm on windows not `linux`. Those commands are not available in windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on Windows, you can use command line like below (refer to [@dbenham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711569/windows-batch-file-concatenate-all-files-in-subdirectories)):

```
for /r "c:\javascripts" %F in (*.js) do @type "%F" >>concatenated.js
```

If on Linux or Mac, you can use `find`:

```
find ./v2/dist/js/ -name '*.js' -exec cat {} \; > ./build/a.min.js
```

Comment: Files are in multiple folders & there are folder inside folders. As I mentioned in question, `type` can take all js files inside a folder without `for` loop  using `*.js` with folder path but no way for having all files inside subfolders inside the folder too.

Comment: In `for` statement, `/r` means *recursive*, which gets all files inside subfolder into consideration. Refer to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx

Comment: @PranavSingh is your question correctly answered? If yes, maybe you can "accept" this answer?

Comment: sorry for late response, I moved away with some other solution & never tried this. Thanks for ur help